# PHP file not found in AJAX call in Twig

Tags: ajax, symfony, twig

I am practicing unit test for AJAX call in Symfony 2.8.

Here is my code :

```
<script>
QUnit.test("test dynamic fill", function (assert) {
            var ajax = $("#ajax"); //my div to fill
            $("#feed_the_ajax").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "echo.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {text: "Hello world !"},
                    success: function (data) {
                        ajax.text(data);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                    }
                });
                assert.ok(!ajax.text() == "Hello world !", "Hello !");
            });
            assert.ok(!ajax.text() == "Hello world !", "Answer me ...");
        });
</script>
```

It is located in a twig file.

echo.php file is just like this :

```
<?php
if($_POST['text'] != ""){
    return $_POST['text'];
}
```

When I run the code, it tells me that "echo.php" is not found.

So there is two questions :

1) First, am I doing it wright to call an AJAX like this (in the twig) or should I use the Controller ?

2) Secondly, where should I put my PHP file to avoid 404 error ?

Thanks for your answers,
Telest

---

**EDIT 8/07/16**

Greetings,

I am back to share with you my solution.
I simply use a bundle called FOSJsRoutingBundle, that will generate a route to a function in the controller. 
Then I "convert" my "echo.php" into a function with a route in my controller, answered a Response and ... Tadaa !

Solved !

Thanks for your help !
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

You can't put JS in the Controller.

But you can save it in a javascript file (located at app/Ressources/public/js/MyJSfile.js)

And include it in your twig template with :

```
{% javascripts 'js/MyJSfile.js' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

(see here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html)

2)

Your echo.php should be in the web folder.
(but your server configuration needs to permit it, basically when you install symfony, you redirect all requests to app.php or app_dev.php).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I have just move all my JS in a file and my "echo.php" in the web folder. Now, how can I allow my server use "echo.php" ?